# How to specify a space as part of a wildcard string for bulk renaming of files

Tags: command-line, rename, filenames, wildcards

I have approximately 1200 songs in a folder whose filenames are structured as follows:

artist_name - song_name.mp3

For example:

```
Billy Joel - Piano Man.mp3
The Beatles - Nowhere Man.mp3
```

I'd like to use DOS commands in Windows PowerShell to do a bulk rename of these files to remove the space on either side of the hyphen.  I don't want to remove all spaces, however.  The basic problem is to be able to include spaces in the filename specs in order to change " - " to "-" in all files in a directory.  Here are some examples of what I'd like to change:

Existing filenames

```
Billy Joel - Piano Man.mp3
The Beatles - Nowhere Man.mp3
```

Desired filenames

```
Billy Joel-Piano Man.mp3
The Beatles-Nowhere Man.mp3
```

Can someone think of a DOS command that could be executed at the command prompt to make such a change on all files in the directory?

I've found that to list all such files with a DIR command, I can use:

```
DIR asterisk+doublequote+space+hyphen+space+doublequote+asterisk+dot+asterisk
```

I had to write it out that way because the actual syntax appears to be treated as formatting instructions here in this forum.

This lists all files which have the 3-character string of space-hyphen-space.

Surely, there must be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this command:

```
ls | %{ ren $_ ($_.name -replace ' - ','-') }
```

using Powershell. This replaces `{space}-{space}` with `-`.

Comment: It took only 8 short minutes for my problem to be solved!

Comment: Thank you very much, Jonno, this worked perfectly.  I appreciate your kindness.  Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a File Manager program like "[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com)" which has a very powerful bulk rename function built in.